# regular GUI changed to plain UI while updating record in october cms

Tags: octobercms

I have created an Industry plugin in the backend. Now whenever I add records or make any changes in the plugin, while trying to update single record the regular GUI of October CMS is changed to something like this. I even checked the version of php, composer and October. There should not be any issue.
What might be the problem? Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: can you try to check dev tools may be something wrong or error there?

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser console, there may be an error for missing css / js